# How do I use a Meteor app running on localhost from a mobile phone on the same network?

Tags: meteor

I want to test an application in Meteor, on localhost with a mobile phone on the same network, can you help me how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just browse to the IP/port of the app on your local net. For instance, if you're starting the meteor app at the standard meteor port on host 10.0.1.25 on your local net, then enter 10.0.1.25:3000 as the url in the browser on your mobile device.

Comment: The IP is 192.168.1.3 (static IP). If I go there with the mobile phone, it shows the contents of the folder, and that is ok. If i go to 192.168.1.3:3000, it redirects to 192.168.1.3 and says "This page is not available".